# Position of Div is not consistence across browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a search bar with a clear button. The clear button is visible if there is text in the search field. I used JavaScript for this. Further, I used absolute position to move the clear button to the right side of my search input field. The problem is, that when the top is being adjusted, it is inconsistent across browsers (Chrome and Safari).

Can anyone tell me how to solve this? I am attaching part of my code below

```js
const searchContainer = document.querySelector('.search-bar');
const searchInput = document.querySelector('.search');
const clearButton = document.getElementById("clear-button");
const htmlElement = document.body;


searchInput.addEventListener('click', function() {
  searchContainer.classList.add('expanded');
  htmlElement.classList.add('overflow-hidden');
  htmlElement.classList.add("dimmed");

  toggleClearButton(); // Call the function to toggle clear button visibility
});


document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (!searchContainer.contains(event.target)) {
    searchContainer.classList.remove('expanded');
    htmlElement.classList.remove('overflow-hidden');
    htmlElement.classList.remove('dimmed');

    toggleClearButton(); // Call the function to toggle clear button visibility
  }
});



// Function to toggle the visibility of the clear button
function toggleClearButton() {
  if (searchInput.value.trim() !== '' && searchContainer.classList.contains('expanded')) {
    clearButton.style.cssText = 'display: block';
  } else {
    clearButton.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

searchInput.addEventListener('input', toggleClearButton);

// Function to clear the input field when the clear button is clicked
clearButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission if the clear button is inside a form
  searchInput.value = '';
  searchInput.focus(); // Optionally, set focus back to the input field
  toggleClearButton(); // Call the function to toggle clear button visibility
});
```

```css
.rightnav {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2.9%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.search-bar {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 1.59rem;
}

.search {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  color: #111111;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
}

.expanded {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50% background-color: white;
  z-index: 99;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.search-bar.expanded form {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.expanded .search {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.expanded .search:focus {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.expanded .search-button {
  display: none;
}

.suggestion-box {
  display: none;
}


/* positioning of the clear button-----------------*/
#clear-button {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-weight: 500;
  border-top-right-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20.5px;
  padding: 25.15px;
}

.search-bar.expanded #clear-button {
  right: 20rem;
}

.search-bar.expanded {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.search-bar.expanded .suggestion-box {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 800px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 1px #c8c8c8;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="rightnav">
<div class="search-bar">
  <form>
    <input class="search bt-outline" type="text" placeholder="Search">


  </form>
  <button class="bt-outline" id="clear-button">Clear</button>
  <div class="suggestion-box">
    <p> Popular Search</p>
    <p>Shoes</p>
    <p>shirts</p>
    <p>Jackets</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don't work with `position:absolute` if not necessary.**

I only fixed the button here:

First you should put the button inside the form element.
Then you can align the Input field and the button within the form, next to each other with flexbox:

```
.search-bar.expanded form {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

Secondly i changed the div.search-bar.expanded from `flex-direction:column` to `flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap`, then I put a `div` wrapper around your suggestion box with 100% width so this will wrap below the input-field,
and inside this wrapper I put your suggestion-box `max-width: 800px` that's centered

Also I removed the position absolute on your button and input field.
Here is the whole code:

```css
.rightnav {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2.9%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.search-bar {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 1.59rem;
}

.search {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  color: #111111;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
}

.expanded {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 99;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.search-bar.expanded form {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.expanded .search {
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.expanded .search:focus {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.expanded .search-button {
  display: none;
}

.suggestion-box {
  display: none;
}


/* positioning of the clear button-----------------*/

#clear-button {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-weight: 500;
  border-top-right-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  padding: 25.15px;
}

.search-bar.expanded {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.suggestion-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.search-bar.expanded .suggestion-box {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 800px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 1px #c8c8c8;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="rightnav">
  <div class="search-bar">
    <form>
      <input class="search bt-outline" type="text" placeholder="Search NEN" />
      <button class="bt-outline" id="clear-button">Clear</button>
    </form>
    <div class="suggestion-wrapper">
      <div class="suggestion-box">
        <p>Popular Search</p>
        <p>Shoes</p>
        <p>shirts</p>
        <p>Jackets</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```